# JSON Outline tool not appearing in VS 2015 or 2017

Tags: .net, json, visual-studio, azure

When I open a JSON ARM file the outline does not appear in the Cloud Explorer window. I also do not get intellisense for the template(I have the Azure SDK installed). Here is the file

```
    {
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {

  },
  "variables": {

  },
  "resources": [

  ],
  "outputs": {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by removing Azure SDK 3.0 and going back to 2.9(November 2016).

Answer (score 1):

In VS2017 go to `Visual Studio Installer` and make sure `Azure Development` workload is installed

[image]

Then go to VS2017 and open `View` > `Other Windows` > `JSON Outline`

[image]

Comment: Same fix for vs2019 also.

Answer (score 0):

I had to show it manually and even then if I opened a json file standalone it didn't show the layout. However when I opened the JSON file as a VS project it worked fine